# Bad: how to fix the problem with colliders?

Tags: javascript

collider doesn't work for me, can you help me I'm developing my engine. The problem is that the script checks for a collision with
an unknown collider.

```
function isCollide(y, x, w, h, x2, y2, w2, h2) {
    square(w, h, x, y, 'red')
   // square(w2, h2, x2, y2, 'blue')
    return !(
        ((y + h) < (y2)) ||
        (y > (y2 + h2)) ||
        ((x + w) < x2) ||
        (x2 > (x2 + w2))
    );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldhPy.png)

I thought that the colliders would be normal, but it turned out not to be so.

Answer (score 0):

Function colid() accept 2 rectangle objects and return true if collide :)
Not sure what you mean by "unknown collider"

[MDN 2D collision detection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection)

```js
const canv = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canv.getContext("2d");

canv.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canv.height = document.body.clientHeight;

ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.fillStyle = "black";

const rect1 = { 'x': canv.width/2, 'y': canv.height/2, 'w': 200, 'h': 100 };
const rect2 = { 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'w': 200 , 'h': 100};

function colid(rec1, rec2) {
  return rec1.x + rec1.w > rec2.x && rec1.x < rec2.x + rec2.w && rec1.y + rec1.h > rec2.y && rec1.y < rec2.y + rec2.h
}

function main() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);
  ctx.fillRect(rect1.x - rect1.w/2, rect1.y - rect1.h/2, rect1.w, rect1.h);
  ctx.strokeStyle = colid(rect1, rect2) ? "red" : "black";
  ctx.strokeRect(rect2.x - rect2.w/2, rect2.y - rect2.h/2, rect2.w, rect2.h);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
}

window.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  rect2.x = e.offsetX;
  rect2.y = e.offsetY;
});

window.requestAnimationFrame(main);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```